# Why coefficients are different when pooled ols and random effect applied?

Tags: least-squares, random-effects-model, pooling

Does anybody know why the coefficients of an equation which is estimated by Random effect estimators and Pooled OLS is different from each other?

Comment: To me, the question rather ought to be: "why would they be *equal* to each other?" These are two different estimators - why would you expect them to produce identical estimates for any given finite sample?`